# How can I convert non-standard date data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, text-formatting

For some silly reason the data I've been provided has dates in the following format: mmddyyyy but if the date is something beginning with zero (e.g. 03132010) then it shows up without the leading zero. I need to update all of these dates so that if they don't already have two mm fields they have a 0 added to the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can highlight the cells concerned, right click then format cells. You can select how the cells will handle formats.

Please see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/81518 <-- You can do it using custom formats.

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any option to format the date in this manner, and selecting any other format results in all those without a leading 0 to become ######

Comment: @Dave Mackey, I have updated my answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd try it is somewhat convoluted, but I tested it and it works.

Make a copy of your sheet. Add five columns after the date. In the first column of the new ones, use the formula `if(length(A1=8);left(A1;2);left(A1;1))` (assuming that your date is in cell A1). In the second one, use `right(A1;6)`. In the third, use `left(c1;2)`. In the fourth, use `right(c1;4)`.

To get the date in the fifth column, formatted as a date, use `date(e1;d1;b1)`.

Actual formula names may vary, I backtranslated them from German.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this formula in an extra column that pre-pends a zero.  Some assumptions:

1. your original value is in cell A2
2. the format of all cells is "General"
3. the month is the only part of the date that would NOT have a
   leading zero

=IF(LEN(A2)<>8,"0"&A2,A2)

Does this do what you want?